# How to bulk dismiss apple script dialogs?

Tags: python, macos, applescript

I'm calling a apple script dialog from python as so:

```
import subprocess

applescript = """
display dialog "Some message goes here..." ¬
with title "This is a pop-up window" ¬
with icon caution ¬
buttons {"OK"}
"""

subprocess.call("osascript -e '{}'".format(applescript), shell=True)
```

However, based on certain conditions of my app, the notifications may go into the 100s i.e., too many dialogs may get queued up and dismissing each one manually by clicking on their respective "OK" buttons wouldn't be feasible. So what I'm looking for is a another apple script that I can use probably straight from the applescript editor that can clear these dialogs for me. A bonus would be to capture their text & timestamps into a text file, but just clearing them is something I need.

I'm new to Mac/applescipts and have not found a valid solution. I've tried the following:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "NotificationCenter"
        set numwins to (count windows)
        repeat with i from numwins to 1 by -1
            click button "OK" of window i
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

and

```
tell application "System Events"
    click button 1 of windows of application process "TextEdit"
end tell
```

Can someone guide me in terms of how to achieve this? Thanks!

Alternately,

If there is a way to "separate" notifications for each iteration of:

```
b =  """
display notification "All graphics have been converted 2." with title "My Graphic Processing Script" subtitle "Processing is complete." sound name "Frog"
"""
subprocess.call("osascript -e '{}'".format(a), shell=True)
```

then, that would work as well. Currently what's happening is each iteration of the notification is stacking on top of each other- ie., when multiple of them gets generated, I only see the latest one, or the number of such notifications. I instead would like to see all the notifications- perhaps have them stacked vertically- for eg: first notification displays in top right, and when second notification appears before the first disappears then, the first notification can get pushed downwards and the second one can be displayed on top of that. Similarly the third one can push both the first and second downward and then be on top of them and so forth.

Can this be achieved?

Basically, I need to see the content of all such notifications- either passively or actively requiring clicks. But in both cases, dismissing the notification should not impede my work. This is a monitoring application so based on certain conditions it would throw notifications my way- which the more close to real time, the better- so thats why I need to view all my notifications, as they appear, rather than write to some csv or txt file and me physically check that file periodically- which would be an unsustainable work flow.

Comment: Do you have to choose options on the dialog or just OK? If no options why not use osx notification Center?

Comment: The AppleScript `display dialog` creates a _modal_ window and as such halt any further processing in a script until dismissed, so how are they getting queued up? Also, there seems to be some contradictions in your OP, on one hand you say "A bonus would be to capture their text & timestamps into a text file" but then say "rather than write to some csv or txt file and me physically check that file periodically". So which is it, what do you really want?

Comment: Anyway, you are calling `osascript` to display the dialog and as such to programmatically click the "OK" button, based on the code you've show using a single button, "OK", you would use: `tell application "System Events" to click button 1 of window 1 of process "osascript"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. If you don't like having dialogs, why are you putting dialogs in your script.
Anyhow, here are a couple ideas:

1. Add

   giving up after 1

to your display dialog command, which will dismiss each box automatically after 1 second.

2. In place of the dialog box, how about putting instead a command to write a time stamp or whatever to a text file. Then you can check the text file to see it all worked.